# Change cell value loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I want this part of the code to do is if the value of cell H83 is greater than 22 then I want the code to increase the value of cell R14 which is 0.7 by an increment of 0.01 until either R14 reaches 0.75 or until H83 is less than 22. I have tried:

```
For j = 0.69 To 0.74
w = j + 0.01
    If Range("h83") > 22 Then
    Range("r14").Value = w
        If 21 < Range("h83") < 23 Then Exit For
    End If
Next j
```

This doesn't work and right now I have it so it increases it by 0.01 only once (part in asterisks), full code:

```
Sub C_CreateTestResultTableV2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'helps the code run faster


Dim vInputs, vResults()
Dim c As Integer, i As Integer

'create INPUTS
c = Range("b5").End(xlToRight).Column
vInputs = Range("b5", Cells(9, c))
    'determine last value in the column
    c = UBound(vInputs, 2)

'create RESULTS
ReDim vResults(1 To 4, 1 To c)

For i = 1 To c

'checks to see if t_air_in > 22
If vInputs(1, i) > 22 And vInputs(3, i) < 70 Then
    'set values
    Range("j18") = vInputs(1, i)
    Range("n14") = vInputs(3, i)
    Range("r16") = vInputs(5, i)

    'checks to see if t_air_out = 22 and changes t_wat_in and m_wat_in accordingly
    If Range("h83") > 22 Then
    Range("r16").Value = Range("r16").Value - 3
    End If

    *If Range("h83") > 22 Then
    Range("r14").Value = Range("r14").Value + 0.01
    End If*

    'copy output values into RESULTS
    vResults(1, i) = Range("h83")
    vResults(2, i) = Range("k83")
    vResults(3, i) = Range("z14")
    vResults(4, i) = Range("r15")

End If

    'resets values
    Range("r16").Value = 13
    Range("r14").Value = 0.7

Next i

Range("b96").Resize(4, c) = vResults

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: **For j = 0.69 To 0.74 Step 0.01**

Comment: Ah my bad. That fixed it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to happen until a certain condition is met, but you don't know exactly when that happens, you need a Do-Loop:

```
Do While Range("H83").Value < 23
 Range("R14").Value = Range("R14").value + 0.01
 Range("H83").value = Range("H83").value + x 'If you don't do something with Range("H83"), the loop will go on forever
Loop
```

Edit: From someone who made this mistake more than willing to admit: If you create a do-loop, please make sure that you don't create an infinite loop, because the chance is high that VBA won't respond anymore.

Comment: Yeah happens too often to myself as well haha. Thanks for the answer!